# Progress Data Direct

Tags: odbc, tableau-api, impala, datadirect

```
  We are having cloudera impala as data source. It is required to build a new custom ODBC driver (we need to
```

use our custom rest API,code logic  in the new obdc driver) to read data from impala.

That custom obdc driver needs to be recognised by tableau as custom driver for impala connectivity.

As we are totally new to driver porgramming, we need guidance in the following
    How to build odbc driver for impala?
    How to make tableau recognise the custom build driver?

- Exafluence